# Removing item from observablearray in Knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to learn Knockoutjs and I am having some issues with adding and removing objects to an observablearray.

I have the following viewmodel in which I fetch some data from a webservice and populate some html. This works fine. But what does not work is removing items from the observablearray since it seems the click-event does not call removeEmployee.

```
function EmployeeViewModel(){
    var self=this;

    self.employees=ko.observableArray();

    self.removeEmployee = function(item) {
        self.employees.remove(item);
    };
}

function success(data) {
    EmployeeViewModel.employees=ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(EmployeeViewModel);    
};

ApiCall({
    data: {
      [get data]
    },
    onSuccess: function(data){success(data.result)} 
});
```

and the following html:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: employees">   
    <h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: full_name"> </span>!</h2>  
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.removeEmployee">Remove</button>
 </div>
```

I have tried setting up a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8yX5M/ in which removing items does work. The difference is, that in the jsfiddle the items are not fetched from an external source and that I use removeEmployee rather than $parent.removeEmployee.

Any ideas why the non-jsfiddle version is not working ?

thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Because your success function isn't setting the value of the observableArray, it is resetting the object's definition -

```
function success(data) {
    EmployeeViewModel.employees(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
    ko.applyBindings(EmployeeViewModel);    
};
```

Use the setter function on EmployeeViewModel.employees by using the () and passing in a value.

Comment: I tried your code, but now no data is databound. So success2 below databinds but success does not.

function success2(data) {
 EmployeeViewModel.employees=ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(EmployeeViewModel);    
};


function success(data) {
    EmployeeViewModel.employees(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
    ko.applyBindings(EmployeeViewModel);    
};

Comment: Btw I tried setting a debugger-statement in my success-function. And it is not being called when I press the "remove"-button. So I guess for some reason, the event is not being fired

Answer (score -2):

Turned out it was because I did not instantiate EmployeeViewModel to a global variable before mapping the data.

The working code is

```
'use strict';

var employeeViewModel=new EmployeeModel();
function EmployeeModel(){
    var self=this;
    self.employees=ko.observableArray();

self.removeEmployee = function(item) {
    self.employees.remove(item);
    };
}

function getEmployeesSuccess(data,controlIds) {
    employeeViewModel.employees=ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    var _i=0;
    for (var _total=controlIds.length; _i < _total; _i++) {
        ko.applyBindings(employeeViewModel,$("#"+controlIds[_i])[0]);    
    }
};

/* Databinds employeedata to an array of controls */
/* controlIds=Array of controls*/
function DataBindEmployees(controlIds)
{
ApiCall({
    data: {
      [get data]
    },
    onSuccess: function(data){getEmployeesSuccess(data.result, controlIds)} });
};
```